# Which FaceAPI to Verify a person?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I'm new to the cognitive services, and going through the docs still a little confused as to which of the methods are needed to verify someone who appears in two different images.  Basically want to make sure the person is the same person in both images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Face verification**

This will check the likelihood that two faces belong to the same person. The API will return a confidence score about how likely it is that the two faces belong to one person. If the faces in 2 images are matching then the confidence score returned by the method will be nearer to 1.

You can refer documentation [here](https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a) about **Face- Verify**.